# Login roles vs user password table

Tags: java, postgresql, authentication, passwords

Is it better to create postgresql login roles for each java application user or a user table with usernames and passwords?

In case two, how can i login into the db with an username and password stored on a table?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL roles are now conceptually the same thing as what you're proposing, users with passwords:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/user-manag.html

> The concept of roles subsumes the concepts of "users" and "groups". In PostgreSQL versions before 8.1, users and groups were distinct kinds of entities, but now there are only roles. Any role can act as a user, a group, or both
>
> Database roles are conceptually completely separate from operating system users. In practice it might be convenient to maintain a correspondence, but this is not required. Database roles are global across a database cluster installation (and not per individual database). To create a role use the CREATE ROLE SQL command
>
> In order to bootstrap the database system, a freshly initialized system always contains one predefined role. This role is always a "superuser", and by default (unless altered when running initdb) it will have the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database cluster. Customarily, this role will be named postgres. In order to create more roles you first have to connect as this initial role.
>
> Every connection to the database server is made in the name of some particular role, and this role determines the initial access privileges for commands issued on that connection. The role name to use for a particular database connection is indicated by the client that is initiating the connection request in an application-specific fashion. For example, the psql program uses the -U command line option to indicate the role to connect as. Many applications assume the name of the current operating system user by default (including createuser and psql). Therefore it is often convenient to maintain a naming correspondence between roles and operating system users.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17043226)

Comment: Right you are. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Login roles should be ok as long as you do not have very complicated bussines logic. If you go with table with usernames and passwords you need aditional tables to store grants and program to manage rights which will require lot of work.